# Restoring SQL Server databases on to UAT from Prod

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I would like to restore prod databases to UAT on a regular schedule. I want to see if this is possible in MS SQL Server.

1. Full Backup prod at beginning of month
2. Restore UAT with the above full backup. Keep a snapshot of UAT
3. Work on UAT
4. Restore UAT to that snap shot
5. Restore UAT from differential backups (rather than full to save time) in prod from the snapshot time.
6. Update snapshot to the new snapshot
7. Continue steps 3-6 until end of month.

Comment: Step 5 and later does not work. There is no way you can restore UAT from diff backups without restoring full backups first.

Comment: Stop thinking in months. THinks in weeks. Once you ahve it automated, you can do it every weekend, which is really nice as it is 2 days most people do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a job to automate it, or a  maintenance plan in MS SQL Server, but restoring differential backups without a full backup first is not possible in SQL Server as suggested by @jyao.